# Help with theorem used in Boolean Expression Simplification

Tags: boolean-algebra

I need to simplify the following expression
$$(a+b+\bar c)(a+c+d)(\bar a +b+c) $$

This is what I've done:
$$=(a+(b+\bar c)(c+d))(\bar a+b+c)$$
$$=(a+bc+bd+\bar cc+\bar cd)(\bar a+b+c)$$
$$=(a+bc+bd+\bar cd)(\bar a+b+c)$$
$$=a \bar a +ab+ac+\bar abc+bc+bc+ \bar abd+bd+bdc+\bar a \bar cd+b \bar cd+c \bar cd$$
$$=ab+ac+bc+bd+\bar a \bar cd$$

My textbook has given the final answer as $$ab+ac+bc+\bar a \bar cd$$
but I haven't been able to figure out which theorem was used to simplify bd. How was bd removed from their final answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $b$ is true and $d$ is true, then one of

$(ab), (bc),$ or $(\overline{a}~\overline{c}~d)$ must be true.

Therefore, the $(bd)$ term is redundant, and thus eliminated.